# HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error Parsing field value JSONObject cant be cast as Int

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am uploading a minified JSON file to S3 via a lambda function that extracts data with an API call and saves some data as a JSON. A glue crawler then crawls the bucket and finds a new JSON file. Crawler adds a table to a database in the data catalog. When I query the database in Athena I get the error message below. I am not sure why the field might be the full JSON object instead of the INT value. Below is my setup the best that I can describe it.

Any solutions or ideas would be gratefully appreciated.

Query:
SELECT * FROM "<database_name>"."<table_name>" limit 10;

Error Message:
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '{'id': 1, 'name': 'some name', 'is_active': true}' for field 0: org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.

Example File Name:
<time_uploaded>.json
12:00:00.json

Example JSON (actual is minified):

```
[
{'id': 1, 'name': 'some name', 'is_active': true},
{'id': 1, 'name': 'some name', 'is_active': true},
{'id': 1, 'name': 'some name', 'is_active': true}
]
```

Bucket Path:
<bucket_name>/<database_name>/<table_name>/<date_uploaded>/

JSON Classifier:
$[*]

Answer (score 1):

Can't test it right now but this is what I would do:

1. Replace single quotes (') with double quotes (") to enclose keys and string values in JSON documents; I am not sure if Athena can read single quotes JSON.
2. Remove each entry from list and treat then as new line JSON documents. Ex.:

{"id": 1, "name": "some name", "is_active": true}\n

{"id": 1, "name": "some name", "is_active": true}\n

{"id": 1, "name": "some name", "is_active": true}\n

Obs.: Remember that Athena can't read multiple JSON documents in same line. It only reads the first occurence on each line of text file.

4. Check for presence of wrong or unescaped quotes

Comment: Perfect. Single quotes didn't matter. I could not have one array of objects on a single. Each object needed to be on its own line.

Comment: Great! Good to know that single quotes worked. Unfortunately Athena does not understand multiple JSON objects in same line and there is also no way to insert a "separator" different than newlines char (\n, CR-LF, etc.)

Comment: in case you needed to put json in separate lines via lambda, i found this post useful. 
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/append-newline-to-amazon-kinesis-firehose-json-formatted-records-with-python-f58498d0177a
instead of `new Buffer` use `Buffer.from()`